# Is it possible to get the test results of a job using the Java API for Jenkins?

Tags: rest, jenkins

I'm looking at the [Jenkins API for java](https://github.com/cdancy/jenkins-rest) and I see there's a `JobApi` to start/stop Jobs and a `BuildInfo` interface with information about a build in that job. I can't find anything to get the test results of a build though, is it not (yet) implemented or did I miss it?

I mean the results that you would get by calling the endpoints:

- http://`<server>`/job/`<job_name>`/`<build_number>`/testReport/api/json?pretty=true --> returns a `hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult`
- http://`<server>`/job/`<job_name>`/`<build_number>`/testReport/`<package>`/BugReportsTest/`<test_class>`/api/json?pretty=true --> returns a `<hudson.tasks.junit.CaseResult>`

Answer (score 0):

What is being received is a Java Object. One needs to call the `isPassed()` to get whether this particular object passed or not.

Refer to the Javadoc here
https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/junit/hudson/tasks/junit/TestResult.html

This is pretty similar to case result as well where again `isPassed()` to be used to check whether it has passed or not.

Refer to Case Result Javadoc here
https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/junit/hudson/tasks/junit/CaseResult.html

You can know whether the entire build job has passed or not by using the following url:

```
http://<server>/job/<job_name>/<build_number>/api/json?pretty=true
```

A snapshot for entire build has passed or not is as follows:
[image: Entire Build Job Result Success]

Comment: I'm not interested in using the Rest-Call (URLs). My question is: is it possible to get the same information I would get wit the Rest-Call but using the Java API?